# How to test if a custom view with a text is a child under a parent view?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am new to TDD and Espresso. I have the following user story to simplify my explanation:

> User select a tag from the list. After selecting, show the selected tags from the previous activity.

This pretty straight forward. I am coming from activity `A` which launches activity `B`. It is on activity `B` I select tags from. If I press submit, the tags will show on activity `A`. The problem is, I have a custom `TagViewGroup` which inherited from `LinearLayout` and a parent child specific for that group which is `TagView`. Those are very simple layout.

I have written the following test:

```
    @Test
    public void shouldPickAndBindTagToNote()
    {
        onView(withId(R.id.edittext_description_minimized)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.linearlayout_add_note_maximize)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        onView(withId(R.id.relativelayout_quick_action_button)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        onView(withId(R.id.imagebutton_tag)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.coordinatorlayout_tag_list)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

        onView(withText("TODO")).perform(click());
        onView(withText("Critical")).perform(click());
        onView(withText("For Tomorrow")).perform(click());

        onView(withId(R.id.fab_tag_list)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.tagviewgroup_note_tags)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));


// This part checks if the selected tag TODO, Critical, Reminders are on the TagViewGroup        
   onView(withId(R.id.tagviewgroup_note_tags)).check(matches(NoteTagMatcher.hasTag(is("TODO"))));
        onView(withId(R.id.tagviewgroup_note_tags)).check(matches(NoteTagMatcher.hasTag(is("Reminders"))));
        onView(withId(R.id.tagviewgroup_note_tags)).check(matches(NoteTagMatcher.hasTag(is("For Tomorrow"))));
    }
```

Here is my custom matcher:

```
public class NoteTagMatcher
{
    public static Matcher<View> hasTag(final Matcher<String> tagName)
    {
        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>()
        {
            @Override
            protected boolean matchesSafely(View item)
            {
                if(!(item instanceof TagViewGroup))
                    return false;

                TagViewGroup tvg = (TagViewGroup) item;
                int c = tvg.getChildCount();

                for(int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
                {
                    View v = tvg.getChildAt(i);

                    if(!(v instanceof TagView)) continue;

                    TagView tv = (TagView) v;

                    if(tagName.matches(tv.getText()))
                        return true;

                    return false;
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description)
            {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

This test always fail for some reason:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: '' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected:
Got: "TagViewGroup{id=2131624148, res-name=tagviewgroup_note_tags, visibility=VISIBLE, width=468, height=72, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=107.0, child-count=3}"
```

I don't understand this error. But I was able to check it with this simple approach which I just realized:

```
onView(withText("TODO")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
onView(withText("Critical")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
onView(withText("For Tomorrow")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

This is simple and requires less hackish code and its very easy to read and understand but I wanted a little bit of challenge so I went extra mile to implement my own matcher and try to see if I could check if my custom `TagView` that has a string `TODO` does exist under `TagViewGroup`.

As I've said, what I wanted to do is to test if the selected tag (`TagView`) with a specific text does appear under my custom `ViewGroup` (`TagViewGroup`). Given my custom matcher, which is apparently not working, how can I make it so? Any wrongdoings I commit?

Any thoughts on how I can properly test this?

Thanks!